# Import data from HTML page using feeds importer in drupal

Tags: xpath, drupal-7

I'm trying to import some data from a HTML page with feeds importer. The context is this:

```
<table class="tabela">
    <tr valign="TOP">
        <td class="formulario-legenda">Nome:</td>
        <td nowrap="nowrap">
            <b>Raul Fernando de Almeida Moreira Vidal</b>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr valign="TOP">
        <td class="formulario-legenda">Sigla:</td>
        <td>
            <b>RMV</b>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr valign="TOP">
        <td class="formulario-legenda">Código:</td>
        <td>206415</td>
    </tr>
    <tr valign="TOP">
        <td class="formulario-legenda">Estado:</td>
        <td>Ativo</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class="topo">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td class="formulario-legenda">Categoria:</td>
                    <td>Professor Associado</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="formulario-legenda">Carreira:</td>
                    <td>Pessoal Docente de Universidades</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="formulario-legenda">Grupo profissional:</td>
                    <td>Docente</td>
                </tr>
                <tr valign="TOP">
                    <td class="formulario-legenda">Departamento:</td>
                    <td>
                        <a href="uni_geral.unidade_view?pv_unidade=151" 
                           title="Departamento de Engenharia Informática">Departamento de Engenharia Informática</a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I tried with this:

```
/html/body/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]
```

but nothing appears. Can someone help me with the right syntax to obtain `"Grupo Profissional"`?

Answer (score 0):

#### Quick answer that might work

Considering just the HTML sample you provided (which only has two tables) you can select the text you want using this expression, based on the table's position:

```
//table[2]//tr[3]/td[1]/text()
```

This *will work in the HTML you pasted above*. But it *might not work in your actual scenario*, since you might have other tables, the table you want to select has no ID and you didn't suggest some invariant text in your code which could be used to *anchor the context* for the expression. *Assuming* the initial part of your XPath expression (the `div` sequence) is correct, you *might* be able to use:

```
/html/body/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/table[2]//tr[3]/td[1]/text()
```

But it's wuite a fragile expression and vulnerable to any changes in the document.

#### A (possibly) better solution

A *better* alternative is to look for some *identifier* you could use. I can only guess, since I don't know your code. In your sample code, I would guess that `Codigo` and the number following it `206415` might be some identifier. If it is, you could use it to anchor your context. First you select it:

```
//table[.//td[text()='Código:']/following-sibling::td='206415']
```

The expression above will select the table which contains a `td` with the *exact* text `Código:` followed by a `td` containing the exact text `206415`. This will create a *unique context* (considering that the number is an unique identifier). *From* that context, you can now select the text you want, which is inside the *next table* (`following-sibling::table[1]`). This is the context of the second table:

```
//table[.//td[text()='Código:']/following-sibling::td='206415']/following-sibling::table[1]
```

And this should select the text you want (`Grupo profissional:`) which is in the third row `tr[3]` and first cell/column `td[1]` of that table:

```
//table[.//td[text()='Código:']/following-sibling::td='206415']/following-sibling::table[1]//tr[3]/td[1]/text()
```